# How to find max flags which set in array, distance between two flags must greater or equal than numbers of flags

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an ascending order array. If two elements has distance (|A[j]-A[i]|) >= A.Length, they will be set flag.

Example: Array [1, 3, 5, 10]

When number of flags is 2, I can set them on A[0] and A[2].

When number of flags is 3, I can set them on A[0], A[2] and A[3].

When number of flags is 4, I can't set because |A[1]-A[0]| = 2 < 4.

So the maximum flags is 3.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can use (if possible) or omit every item. So it is not hard to make recursive function (assuming `n=A.Length`) (Python-like pseudocode)

```
def maxFlags(A, idx, minvalue):
    if idx >= n:
        return 0

    result = maxFlags(A, idx + 1, minvalue) # not use current item A[idx]

    if A[idx] >= minvalue:  #we can try to use current item, updating low limit
         return max(result, 1 + maxFlags(A, idx + 1, A[idx] + n))
```